# Mongodb update pipeline update a field of a element inside a nested array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I have a collection that contains objects such as this.

```
{
  materials: {
    "m1": {
      inventory: [
        {
          price: 100,
          amount: 65
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see inventory is an array deep inside the hierarchy. I want to update the `amount` field of it.

From the client I receive the material id (`"m1"`) and the inventory index (`0`).

I have to use an update pipeline because I am setting and unsetting some other fields in this document.

This is what I tried:

```
await products.findOneAndUpdate(filters, [
  {
    $set: {
      "materials.m1.inventory.0.amount": 100,
    },
  },
]);
```

But it creates a new field named 0 inside the 0th element and sets the `amount` inside that object. So the resulting document looks like this.

```
{
  materials: {
    "m1": {
      inventory: [
        {
          0: {
            amount: 100
          }
          price: 100,
          amount: 65
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Whereas what I want is this:

```
{
  materials: {
    "m1": {
      inventory: [
        {
          price: 100,
          amount: 100
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The only way for me to identify which element in the array to update is the index of it.

I am using nodejs mongodb driver. How to write the `$set` stage for this update pipeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think any other straightway to update the specific index position element using aggregation pipeline,

- `$range` to generate array from 0 to length of `materials.m1.inventory` array
- `$map` to iterate loop of above range array
- `$cond` to check current element is 0 then go to update part otherwise return element from `materials.m1.inventory` by input index
- `$arrayElemAt` to get specific element from `materials.m1.inventory`
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with `amount` updated property

```
await products.findOneAndUpdate(filters, [
  {
    $set: {
      "materials.m1.inventory": {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $range: [0, { $size: "$materials.m1.inventory" }]
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this", 0] }, // 0 position
              {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  { $arrayElemAt: ["$materials.m1.inventory", "$$this"] },
                  { amount: 100 } // input amount
                ]
              },
              { $arrayElemAt: ["$materials.m1.inventory", "$$this"] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0J0BSSgZjxX)

Comment: Very good solution. That `$mergeObjects` came in handy here.

Comment: I don't think there is need to iterate you could just use $arrayElemAt and $mergeObjects to prepare the updated element followed by $concatArrays and $slice to join the array as noted in the other answer - not sure which is efficient solution

Comment: @s7vr you are right, we are not sure but if OP wants to update any other position instead of 0th, then he can by my solution. the other answer is a very good solution only for 0th position update.

Comment: I do want to update other indexes. And also sometimes multiple indexes of the same array. This works best for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `findOneAndUpdate` using an aggregation pipeline is that you can only use `$set`, `$unset` and `$replaceWith` (with their aliases). It seems like that `$set`, or `$addFields`, is not capable of overwriting objects inside arrays, so you can simply re-create the whole array with the changes you need. You are basically forced to build your query like this:

```
db.collection.update(filters,
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "materials.m1.inventory": {
      ...
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This is my implementation but there can be more straightforward ways (See edit that replaces the single-object array):

```
db.collection.update(filters,
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "materials.m1.inventory": {
        $concatArrays: [
          [
            {
              price: {
                $getField: {
                  field: "price",
                  input: {
                    $first: "$materials.m1.inventory"
                  }
                }
              },
              amount: 100
            }
          ],
          {
            $slice: [
              "$materials.m1.inventory",
              1,
              {
                $size: "$materials.m1.inventory"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I am using `$concatArrays` to *concat*:

1. An array with a single object, which is the one at index 0 but with the `amount` field set to 100
2. The slice of the `inventory` array starting from index 1.

Obviously, if the index was different than 0, you would have to take a first slice `inventory[0:index]`, a single-object array (see point 1), and the slice `inventory[index + 1:]`.

[Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cn6qMB_MDWg) the demo.

---

EDIT:
The `$mergeObjects` part proposed by @turivishal is definitely better than my single-object array: whether you have 2 or 20 fields the code is the same.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me to understand mongodb pipelines better. I guess the updating array indexes doesn't work because the syntax I expected to work is ambiguous on whether to update 0th element or add a new field called 0. Yeah the other answer is easier to use as I have to update other indexes and sometimes multiple indexes of the same array.

Comment: As I said you can always do 2 slices and take the object in the middle index. I do not know which solution is better in terms of performances, but the accepted one is certainly easy to understand :)